# Terminal doesn't print colors

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, antergos

My Antergos terminal doesn’t show me any colors when executing scripts. I have a fresh instalation, with no tweaks. I have zsh and oh-my-zsh, but the configurations are the default ones.
[image]

You can see that all the output is white, it should be colorful:
[image]

This happen when I install programs, blanks spaces are text:
[image]

Selectable text:

```
➜  ~  yaourt gnome-terminal 
1 extra/gnome-terminal 3.18.2-1 (gnome) [installed]
    The GNOME Terminal Emulator
2 aur/gnome-terminal-dark-variant 3.18.2-1 (10)
    The GNOME Terminal Emulator - Patched to bring back 'Use dark theme variant' option in preferences
3 aur/gnome-terminal-fedora 3.18.2-1 (31)
    The GNOME Terminal Emulator with Fedora patches
4 aur/gnome-terminal-git 3.15.91.5228.e5f7763-1 (2)
    The GNOME Terminal Emulator. Git Version
5 aur/neovim-gnome-terminal-wrapper 2-3 (0)
    A wrapper for running neovim in a separate instance of gnome-terminal
==> Introduzca el número de los paquetes desea instalar (ejemplos: 1 2 3 ó 1-3)
==> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
==>
```

I tried to customize the profiles, with no success, I tried a fresh instalation with the same ISO in my laptop with no problems, but I don't want to reinstall Antergos in this machine.

`tput colors` outputs **256**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to have been fixed, but the cause was a hardcoded check for the `TERM` environment variable equal to `xterm`.  If (as indicated in the question) you had `xterm-256color`, then the check would fail.

You can see one of the diff's which is part of the change to fix this problem in the [git repository](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/896d1d71f836295d93c5f755703f7643c1983d04#diff-fc0630666d6226318ea87b11459d0d59L240), in this chunk of deleted lines:

```
-    /**
-     * Returns whether we are a terminal and have colour capabilities
-     *
-     * @return bool
-     */
-    private function isColorTerminal()
-    {
-        if (function_exists('posix_isatty')) {
-            $result = posix_isatty(STDOUT);
-        } else {
-            // See if STDOUT is a character device (S_IFCHR)
-            $stat = fstat(STDOUT);
-            $result = ($stat['mode'] & 0170000) === 0020000;
-        }
-
-        if (defined('PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD') && $result) {
-            $result = false !== getenv('ANSICON')
-            || 'ON' === getenv('ConEmuANSI')
-            || 'xterm' === getenv('TERM');
-        }
-
-        return $result;
-    }
-
```